# Статическая линковка SDL2 в Code::Blocks (mingw32)

Tags: c++, static, sdl2, sdl

Я в данный момент изучаю SDL2, перешёл с SFML в котором была статическая линковка, на тот момент я пользовался VS22++, на официальном сайте SFML была информация о том, как статически слинковать библиотеку с проектом. Но вот у SDL я такого не нашёл, облазил почти весь интернет, находил информацию как это сделать, но у меня не получалось. Например, я пробовал в "других опциях компоновщика" писать -static (или включать флаг Static linking в "Флаги компилятора") но с ним мне выдавало кучу ошибок, или в "Библиотеки компоновщика" из папки lib подключать все файлы ~.a, но программа всё равно требовала SDL2.dll и SDL2_image.dll (даже если они были в папке с .cpp файлом, а у .exe файла уже не было)

PS: Пользуюсь Windows 10 Pro, Code::Blocks mingw32

Добавлено:
При попытке запустить .exe файл пишет следующее:

[image: Ошибка 1: SDL2_image.dll] [image: Ошибка 2: SDL2.dll]
[image: Ошибка 3: libwinpthread.dll]

Если с первыми двумя понятно, что это связано с тем что библиотеки SDL статически не линкуется, то как исправить 3 ошибку? Я знаю что такой файл есть в папке Code::Blocks и что добовление его к проекту исправит эту ошибку (не пробовал) но всё таки я хочу статически связывать все необходимые библиотеки (возможно -static исправил бы 3 ошибку, за то с ним появляются ещё 161 ошибка: [image: -static])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два способа.

1. Ручной.

   Полезть в файл `??/lib/pkgconfig/sdl2.pc`, который вы скачали вместе с SDL2, и посмотреть там флаги в строке `Libs.private`. (По идее, для SDL2_image нужно бы сделать то же самое, но там никаких флагов не указано.)

   Скопировать их во флаги линковщика, и добавить `-static`. (Это все после `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, которые уже должны там быть.)

   Убедиться, что папка с `libSDL.a` добавлена в пути поиска линковщика. Тогда из-за `-static` он должен выбрать именно этот файл, что нам и нужно, и проигнорировать `libSDL2.dll.a` или `SDL2.dll`. (То же самое с `libSDL2_image.a`.)
2. Через MSYS2 и pkg-config.

   Как обычно, я рекомендую заменить обычный MinGW на MSYS2, потому что там всегда свежая версия компилятора, и распространенные библиотеки (включая SDL2) можно поставить одной командой.

   В том числе там есть Pkg-Config, который говорит нужные флаги для использования тех или иных библиотек, чтобы не надо было лезть руками в `.pc`-файлы (которые для него и предназначены).

- Сносите свой MinGW.
- Ставите [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).
- Запускаете его ярлыком `MSYS2 UCRT64`. Если сделано правильно, в открышейся консоли будет написано `UCRT64` фиолетовыми буквами. ([в чем разница между ярлыками](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/))
- Обновляетесь командой `pacman -Syuu`. Если при этом консоль закроется - открыть заново и повторить команду для завершения обновления.
- Ставите себе компилятор, отладчик, Pkg-Config, и SDL2.

  ```
  pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pkgconf mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2_image
  ```
- Пробуете скомпилировать командой `` g++ my_code.cpp -static `pkg-config --libs --cflags --static sdl2 SDL2_image` ``.
- Если все успешно, настраиваете CodeBlocks:

  - Путь к компилятору и отладчику меняете на `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`.
  - Во флаги компилятора пишете выхлоп `pkg-config --cflags sdl2 SDL2_image`.
  - Во флаги линковщика пишете `-static` и выхлоп `pkg-config --libs --static sdl2 SDL2_image`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё собралось, вот только при попытке запустить один собранный exe файл появляются 2 окна (консоль и созданное окно) и мгновенно закрываются.
Флаги: -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--high-entropy-va -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lsetupapi -lversion -luuid -lwinmm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -static

Comment: По поводу второго способа. Я обязательно попробую MSYS2, но я хочу всё-таки понять как это сделать в mingw32

Comment: Я сейчас настраивал MSYS2, но я не нашёл где выхлоп, я только позавчера скачал Code::Blocks
Хотя возможно я его нашёл, но мне выдаёт ошибку как с --libs так и с --cflags:
error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs'
error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags'

Comment: Так же при попытке скомпелировать через консоль UCRT64 выдаёт ошибки C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 cannot find pkg-config --libs --cflags --static: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 cannot find sdl2: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 cannot find SDL2_image: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Я забыл к exe файлу закинуть папку с изображением, из-за этого оно сразу закрывалось, большое спасибо. К сожалению, у меня не получилось, по крайней мере сегодня, настроить MSYS2, придётся пользоваться mingw32, ещё раз большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Maxsimilian Отлично! Про ошибки - вы похоже использовали апострофы ' вместо обратных кавычек `. Если не угадал, то покажите команду, которую вы использовали.

Comment: Если что, обратные кавычки запускают команду, записанную внутри них, и подставляют ее вывод во флаги основной команды. Т.е. вы могли бы руками запустить `pkg-config ...`, скопипастить вывод, и вставить во флаги `g++`.

Comment: Да, я использовал ' вместо \`, но с ними тоже ошибки, только немного другие:

 Please specify at least one package name on the command line.
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
o such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
age: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

я ввожу  g++ C:/.../my_code.cpp -static \`pkg-config --libs --cflags --static\` sdl2 SDL2_image (в пути кириллицы нет)

Comment: @Maxsimilian Виноват, закрывающая кавычка была не в том месте. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Ошибок не выдало, только где .exe?

Comment: @Maxsimilian Должен появится. Раз мы не указали имя, по дефолту будет называться `a.exe`.

Comment: Он должен появится в папке рядом с .cpp файлом? Если так, то его там нет

Comment: @Maxsimilian Вроде в текущей папке, а не рядом с `.cpp`. Ну можете указать путь явно через `-o путь/до/программы.exe`.

Comment: Спасибо, можете ещё помочь с настройкой MSYS2 в CodeBlocks? Я просто так и не нашёл "выхлоп"

Comment: @Maxsimilian В смысле запускате эту команду, и смотрите, что она напечатает.